# Insert a record in postgres database table without replacing the existing records

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named employees which has 3 columns ( id , firstname, lastname) which already has 20 records . I want to insert a new record with the id=15 and shift the existing rows with id > 14 without replacing the existing record with id=15.

i tried to move the rows like following but that did not work

```
UPDATE employees
SET id = id + 1
WHERE id >= 15;


INSERT INTO employees (id , firstname, lastname)
VALUES (15, 'john', 'doe' );
```

UPDATE, NOTE : the id is used as a foreign key in another table called product, so if we modify the id's in the employees table we have to modify it in product table too I think

i got the following error **The key “(id)=(17)” already exists**

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to move the old 15 the end and let the new one take its place instead of shifting all rows all the way down from there?

Comment: Why? An id is used to identify a record, not to create an artificial order. You’re now using an integer for the id, but what is you used an UUID? How would you create an order?

Answer (score 2):

Updating tables that reference this ID can be handled automatically if you set up the foreign key columns with an [`on update cascade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES-REFACT-CASCADE) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/p_1b8zI1)

```sql
create table tasks(
  id int generated by default as identity primary key,
  employee_id int references employees(id) 
      on delete set null 
      on update cascade,                               --this
  description text);
```

As to the `id` collision error, [@Frank Heikens raised a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287371/insert-a-record-in-postgres-database-table-without-replacing-the-existing-record/77287712#comment136253719_77287371). You're putting `id` column on double duty: one of uniquely identifying rows, another of defining order of some sort. By dispatching these functions to different columns you wouldn't have to cascade identity changes all over the place whenever you just want to change order: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/jsAUPwkn)

```sql
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN my_order int UNIQUE DEFERRABLE;
UPDATE employees SET my_order=id;

UPDATE employees
SET my_order = my_order + 1
WHERE my_order >= 15;

INSERT INTO employees (id, my_order, firstname, lastname)
VALUES (21, 15,'john', 'doe' );
```

You can reorder things all you want and the unique constraint violation checks will be [deferred](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) and carried out at the end of the entire operation, not row-by-row. And all previous foreign key associations remain untouched.

---

On a small number of ordered samples in a bunch of fresh test tables, it's possible to get rid of the `id` collision error by forcing and ordered batch update:

```sql
WITH update_batch AS (
  SELECT id,
         id+1 AS new_id 
  FROM employees WHERE id >= 15 
  ORDER BY id DESC) --this makes sure the last one moves first, making room
UPDATE employees AS old
SET id = new_id
FROM update_batch AS new 
WHERE old.id=new.id;
```

In a real-life scenario it's near impossible to make this work reliably. It depends on [the planner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) *somehow* deciding to target the updated rows in your desired order.

> [the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> [A target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8)

The error you got is because your primary key constraint is by default [`not deferrable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-DEFERRABLE) so the uniqueness of the `id` is checked row-by-row during the `update` operation. Trying to update the first row with `id=15` it already sees `id=16` is occupied by the next row.

Making your primary key constraint [`deferrable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) lets PostgreSQL check for constraint violations at the end of transaction instead, which would solve the problem of your `update` failing, like it does above in the example with a separate `my_order` column. Problem is, if you wanted to keep both identity and order to be handled by `id` alone, making its unique constraint `deferrable` would stop you from being able to use it for foreign keys: [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/FMew5g4j).

If you forced it to process things in reverse, so that each row would first make room for the next one to take over its `id`, this could work ([demo4](https://dbfiddle.uk/-S571EB7)).

Unfortunately, there's no stable, predictable way in Postgres implementation of plain SQL language to force any particular order upon the `update` statement: see how it still [works if with 142_987](https://dbfiddle.uk/TQ9hD7lh) rows, [then one more breaks it on 142_988](https://dbfiddle.uk/wmqJGLo2).

It's possible to execute an ordered update in non-SQL [user-defined routines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) (e.g. [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)), most of the time at the cost of performance or reliability, or both.

Comment: Is the `UPDATE` statement guaranteed to follow the order of `update_batch`?

Comment: @Bergi I initially assumed it wouldn't work, but kept testing this up to 100k samples and since it kept on working, I figured I'd post and run this by the doc later, attaching adequate quotes. Then I came back and in the doc, I only found reason to doubt why it worked in the first place. Then it broke at exactly 142988 samples, and couldn't be forced back in order precisely because PostgreSQL doesn't offer any control over the update sequence. Thanks for pointing this out. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but the trick I've used is to update twice. e.g.

```sql
UPDATE employees
SET id = id + 101
WHERE id >= 15;

INSERT INTO employees (id , firstname, lastname)
VALUES (15, 'john', 'doe' );

UPDATE employees
SET id = id - 100
WHERE id >= 16;
```

Another alternative is to remove the constraint and then add it back again but that's even uglier.

Whatever the approach doing it in a single transaction is probably a good idea.

Comment: thank you for the response , i edited the question, the id is a foreign key in product table  so we have to update the id column in product table .

Answer (score 0):

The last one is maybe good, but

1. Insert 1 new ROW
2. Update Primary Table backwards
3. Update Row with id 15
4. fix foreign Tables

like that:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (SELECT MAX(id) FROM emloyees, '','');

WITH ue AS (
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM employees
WHERE id >= 15 AND id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM emloyees)
ORDER BY id DESC
)
UPDATE employees e
SET firstname = ue.firstname, lastname = ue.lastname
WHERE e.id = ue.id + 1;

UPDATE employees e
SET firstname = 'John', lastname = 'Doe'
WHERE e.id = 15;

UPDATE foreign_table_x SET foreign_key = foreign_key + 1
WHERE foreign_key >= 15;
```

Comment: Why insert the new row first, then move it, then move it again? Just insert it *after* moving the other rows.

Comment: The foreign table should be updated automatically by a cascading reference constraint, and not need an extra statement

Comment: Due to the constraint, you may not be able to push the entire record. The last line is needed because the record remains, only the data moves. since the ID does not change, the linked records are not automatically updated either. If you still want to increase the ID, you should definitely go backwards, and only update the data for record 15. But, I don't think it's lucky to change the PK either.

Comment: One more things, the new row_ID is MAX+1:
    INSERT INTO employees VALUES (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM emloyees, '','');

Comment: What does "*Due to the constraint, you may not be able to push the entire record*" refer to? Sure you can insert the whole row at once. it makes no sense to insert an empty record then fill it later.

Comment: "*the record remains, only the data moves, the ID does not change*" - oh now I see what you're doing there. This is a **really bad idea**.

Answer (score 0):

Then try to change the PK:

```
WITH ue AS (
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM employees
WHERE id >= 15
ORDER BY id DESC
)
UPDATE employees e
SET id = id + 1, firstname = ue.firstname, lastname = ue.lastname
WHERE e.id = ue.id;
```

Then insert row:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (15, 'John','Doe_15');
```

Answer (score -1):

The attribute `id` must be primary key, thus the error. Also, One Must Not fiddle with the Primary Key Values because if they are used in `FK_Constraints` or as Foreign Keys, such manipulation of Primary Key value can be disastrous.

Notwithstanding, one can achieve what you are trying using something known as  `Common Table Expression`. You may look at following `sql`

```
    BEGIN;

WITH updt_employees AS (
    SELECT (id + 1) AS new_id, firstname, lastname
    FROM employees
    WHERE id >= 15
    AND (id + 1) NOT IN (SELECT new_id FROM updt_employees)
)
INSERT INTO employees (id, firstname, lastname)
SELECT 15, 'John', 'Doe'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM updt_employees;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: thank you for the reponse, i edited the question , the id is a foreign key

Comment: This seems to copy the `updt_employees`, not move them, so they are guaranteed to collide? Did you mean to use `DELETE … RETURNING …`?

Comment: karim1990, I have modified the `sql`. Take a look at the new one above