# Upsert in PostgreSQL: Get number of Updates and Inserts not Affected

Tags: postgresql

when doing an UPSERT statement with postgres, such as

```
INSERT INTO tab1.summary(
table_name, target_field, check_n)
VALUES ('tab1', 'col1', 10),
('tab2', 'col2', 10)
ON CONFLICT(table_name, target_field, check_n)
DO UPDATE SET check_n = 20;
```

, returns nothing as data output, however, the message shows INSERT 0 2, which means that two rows are affected without any error.

However, is there any way to retrieve the number of inserted and updates rows separately as data output?

Answer (score 2):

You can observe a system column [`xmax`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-XMAX):

> `xmax`  The identity (transaction ID) of the deleting transaction, or zero for an undeleted row version. It is possible for this column to be nonzero in a visible row version. That usually indicates that the deleting transaction hasn't committed yet, or that an attempted deletion was rolled back.

You already have it in all tables, it's already set and you can already use it. Normally, unless explicitly referenced, it's just an additional, hidden field, but every row of every table has it.

Rows resulting from an upsert will show their `xmax` field to be zero for inserted and non-zero for updated. That's because under the hood, an `update` is actually a combination of `insert` and `delete`: it inserts a new tuple and deletes the old one, marking it as outdated and ready to be removed by `vacuum` once no other transaction uses a snapshot of the table from before the change: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mD46ab7N)

```sql
with cte as (
  INSERT INTO tab1.summary(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  VALUES ('tab1', 'col1', 10),
         ('tab2', 'col2', 20)
  ON CONFLICT(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  DO UPDATE SET check_n = 20
  RETURNING xmax<>0 as was_updated )
select count(*)filter(where not was_updated) as inserted_count,
       count(*)filter(where     was_updated) as updated_count from cte;
```

You can compare that to the approach using a manually added [reflector column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453513/5298879): [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/edr3swxJ)

```
select * from tab1.summary;
```

| table_name | target_field | check_n | was_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tab1 | col1 | 10 | f |
| tab2 | col2 | 10 | f |

```
INSERT INTO tab1.summary(table_name, target_field, check_n)
VALUES ('tab1', 'col1', 10),
       ('tab2', 'col2', 20)
ON CONFLICT(table_name, target_field, check_n)
DO UPDATE SET check_n = 20, was_updated=true
RETURNING was_updated,xmax;
```

| was_updated | xmax |
| --- | --- |
| t | 732 |
| f | 0 |

```
select * from tab1.summary;
```

| table_name | target_field | check_n | was_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tab2 | col2 | 10 | f |
| tab1 | col1 | 20 | t |
| tab2 | col2 | 20 | f |

Compared to using the glued-on `was_updated` column, it's nice that `xmax` doesn't have to be added at all, because it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.7) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GSLi7nkQ)

```
with cte as (
  INSERT INTO tab1.summary(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  VALUES ('tab1', 'col1', 10),
         ('tab2', 'col2', 10)
  ON CONFLICT(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  DO UPDATE SET check_n = 20
  RETURNING check_n=20 as was_updated)
select count(*)filter(where not was_updated) as inserted_count,
       count(*)filter(where     was_updated) as updated_count from cte;
```

| inserted_count | updated_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |

And if you run it again, forcing the conflict:

| inserted_count | updated_count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |

Of course this method only works if your batch doesn't contain the default `check_n=20`, in which case it'd assume it was updated, not inserted. This can be worked around (although a bit invasively) by adding a reflector column: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/KFi5HS3J)

```sql
alter table tab1.summary add column was_updated boolean default false;

with cte as (
  INSERT INTO tab1.summary(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  VALUES ('tab1', 'col1', 10),
         ('tab2', 'col2', 10)
  ON CONFLICT(table_name, target_field, check_n)
  DO UPDATE SET check_n = 20, was_updated=true
  RETURNING was_updated)
select count(*)filter(where not was_updated) as inserted_count,
       count(*)filter(where     was_updated) as updated_count from cte;
```

Comment: Will that count the inserted rows, the updated rows, or both?

Comment: @Bergi Good point. That would be both - I overlooked that the differentiation between the two is the main clue here. I added a workaround but I think I'll have more

Comment: is there an option to set a kind of a variable when reaching DO UPDATE SET instead of setting a column value? because a row might be updated mulitple times in my scenario, which would require to set the was updated field to false again before triggering the next process

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can return only constants and values from the tables involved in the update and you cannot update something that's not in the table. Also, a row cannot be updated multiple times in a single update. Only a single update in your batch is applied, always; if you want to chain multiple updates, they need to come in separate statements. It's best to pick specifically which change you wish to introduce before passing it to the query - otherwise PostgreSQL doesn't offer any control over which one will be selected, or any guarantee as to which one it'll pick on its own.

Comment: [Here's the source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5) on what you can return and [here's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8) on only a single update per row being applicable and [here's my older post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287712/5298879). That being said, I'd say [the **`xmax`** check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453960/5298879) is the way to go - following your line of thinking, that's the variable that's ***already available and automatically set*** when reaching the `do update set`.