# How to efficiently aggregate rows into arrays, but preserve `NULL` to indicate missing data?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I currently have a database schema like the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Measures(
    expId SERIAL,
    iteration INT NOT NULL,
    value float4 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(expId, iteration)
);
```

So, a table of various measurements, repeated for n iterations.
Though, because we have more data than originally expected, I want to move to a new table layout that instead uses an array column, which overall gives better performance (already tested and benchmarked):

```sql
CREATE TABLE TmpMeasures(
    expId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    values float4[] NOT NULL
);
```

My problem now is how to get the old data into the new format.
The data may look something like this. Not that iterations don't
always produce all data, so there may be `NULL` values in the final array:

```sql
INSERT INTO Measures (expId, iteration, value)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 1.1), (1, 2, 1.2), (1, 3, 1.3),
  (2, 1, 2.1),                           (2, 4, 2.4),
  (3, 1, 3.1),                           (3, 4, 3.4);
```

And conversion could be done with a two step process, roughly like this, to first create the array for an experiment, and then populate the iteration values:

```sql
INSERT INTO TmpMeasures(expId, values)
  SELECT expId, '{}'::float4[] 
  FROM Measures
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

UPDATE TmpMeasures tm
  SET values[iteration] = m.value
  FROM Measures m WHERE tm.expId = m.expId;
```

Though, my problem now is that the `UPDATE` actually only ever seems to take the first iteration, i.e., `iteration = 1`.
I am not quite understanding why that is the case.

I suspect, alternative approaches to `values[iteration]` would try to group by expId, and order by iteration and aggregate that into an array.

Unfortunately, the data isn't perfect, but iterations should line up.

So, the following seems to work, but it's extremely slow, and I don't quite understand why it's needed in the first place.

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..(SELECT max(iteration) FROM Measures m) LOOP
      UPDATE TmpMeasures tm
      SET values[i] = m.value
      FROM Measures m
      WHERE
        tm.expId = m.expId AND
        m.iteration=i;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Why does the "normal" update statement not suffice?
Answer: thanks to @Zegarek's pointer below, this is indeed expected behavior of UPDATE, which only takes a single row from the FROM clause.

So, the more relevant question for me at this point is whether there's a better approach for the data conversion, that produces for instance `[3.1, NULL, NULL, 3.4]` for `expId=3`.

Comment: That’s how `update` works. [*When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8) You could instead use `array_agg(value order by iteration)` to collect them once and give that single final array to `update`

Comment: Do your arrays have holes (i.e. `NULL` elements where no `iteration` exists, but iterations around it do)?

Comment: @Zegarek oh, that's good to know about UPDATE. Never realized that.

@Bergi yeah, the problem is indeed that I either need to create the missing NULL values to use something like `array_agg`, or rely on `values[i]` doing that for me but then take the looping approach. Though, with the looping, I haven't seen it yet terminate on the production database set (some 6GB of rows). So, I am kind of looking for a hopefully faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get min/max `iterations` to later [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) for everything in between.
2. Grab `distinct dExpId` to `left join` it with the iterations to get *`null`* for missing `values`,
3. Then `array_agg(values order by i)`.
4. Instead of `update`, you can [`create table as`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) and [add the constraints later](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-DESC-ADD-TABLE-CONSTRAINT-USING-INDEX): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mZd4OhVG)

```sql
create table if not exists TmpMeasures as
with min_max_iteration as (
  select min(iteration), 
         max(iteration) from Measures)
,distinct_expIds as (
  select distinct expId from Measures)
select expId,
       array_agg(value order by iteration) as "values"
from min_max_iteration
cross join distinct_expIds
cross join generate_series(min,max) g(iteration)
left join Measures using(iteration,ExpId)
group by ExpId;
```

| expId | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {1.1,1.2,1.3,NULL} |
| 2 | {2.1,NULL,NULL,2.4} |
| 3 | {3.1,NULL,NULL,3.4} |

Adding constraints afterwards: ([`identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY) columns are [encouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) over [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)).

```sql
select max(expId)+1 from TmpMeasures;--4

alter table TmpMeasures 
   add primary key (expId)
  ,alter column expId add generated by default as identity(start with 4)
  ,alter column values set not null;
```

The select is needed before that because you can't run it as a scalar subselect in `alter table`. [The demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mZd4OhVG) also shows how to inspect each step, and how to run it as an `update` instead.

If you have some iterations that are missing from all concurrent `Measures` and you want to skip that field in all arrays, you can use `where i in ()` to filter the `generate_series() g(i)`.

If you were looking for performance, on 28k [samples](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nxb-97aJ) (60 `expId`s with 800 `iteration`s each, 40% chance to miss an iteration) this takes `0.25s`: [performance demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wazrKDeN). Looped PL/pgSQL update needs `15.80s`. [In v16](https://dbfiddle.uk/-UC2QAmh), the difference increases to `0.08s` vs *running out of resources and failing*.

---

### The `UPDATE t SET arr[m.k]=m.v FROM m WHERE m.id=t.id` idea

As [mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130781/how-to-efficiently-aggregate-rows-into-arrays-but-preserve-null-to-indicate-m/78132311#comment137741947_78130781), it's [`update`'s fault](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8) it won't work:

> A target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Even though the subscript addresses a specific element in the array value, `update` will not attempt to use more than one undetermined row matched from the source - in effect, for each `id`, only one `(key,value)` pair arrives to be applied, the rest is discarded.

Without `order by` all things are unordered, and `update` doesn't even offer an `order by`. If this worked, you'd see anomalies resulting from the unpredictable order the multiple *row updates* would be applied to the same row. In your case each *row update* targets a different index in the array value so that wouldn't matter as they wouldn't interfere with each other, but that's [not always the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287712/5298879).

Comment: Thanks. Based on this, I ended up with this variation
https://gist.github.com/smarr/5a30c34cc38e274f634b151d9763f93c

Mostly trying to have distinct min/max for each series. 
This runs in about 1.5h on the real data set.

Thank you

Comment: @smarr If you alias the elements from `generate_series() as g(iteration)` all your columns will match, letting you `join..using()` instead of chaining `on a.x=b.x and`. Also, that looks like it'll misalign your arrays, which will be quietly pruned: the distinct, individual min/max will lose leading and trailing *`null`*, without retaining iterations as indexes. [@Bergi's `array_by_subscript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78139144/5298879) also prunes, but it retains iteration-based index alignment, so you can re-align/de-prune/re-inflate them if you plan to append/prepend reliably.

Comment: Thanks. Pruning of iterations would be an issue if the data gets misaligned. So, dropping `null` at the end is fine, but at the beginning would shift iteration values (if I understand correctly). 

Either way, results with my last version "look correct".
Perhaps also interesting, using a temporary table massively improves performance. Am now down to 2min: https://gist.github.com/smarr/5a30c34cc38e274f634b151d9763f93c

Comment: 45x drop in exec time sounds great. `Temp` or [`unlogged`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED) table replacing a cte sometimes helps and it sure is much easier to debug, but if you want to keep this down to a single statement, you might also check if `WITH series_details AS` [**`MATERIALIZED`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-CTE-MATERIALIZATION) `()` doesn't have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the values you want to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO TmpMeasures
SELECT m1.expid, ARRAY[m1.value, m2.value, m3.value,m4.value] as a
FROM (SELECT distinct expid FROM Measures) m0
LEFT JOIN Measures m1 ON m1.expid = m0.expid and m1.iteration = 1
LEFT JOIN Measures m2 ON m2.expid = m0.expid and m2.iteration = 2
LEFT JOIN Measures m3 ON m3.expid = m0.expid and m3.iteration = 3
LEFT JOIN Measures m4 ON m4.expid = m0.expid and m4.iteration = 4
ORDER BY expid
```

Start selecting the unique `expid`s, using `SELECT distinct expid FROM Measures` because not every iteration has all values.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/CiKaAKvq)

output:

| expid | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {1.1,1.2,1.3,NULL} |
| 2 | {2.1,NULL,NULL,2.4} |
| 3 | {3.1,NULL,NULL,3.4} |

EDIT: An alternative solution, because you might have more than 4 iterations.

```
INSERT INTO TmpMeasures
WITH nrs as (
  SELECT * 
  from generate_series(1,(select max(iteration) from Measures)) as f(n)
  cross join (select distinct expid from Measures)
)
SELECT nrs.expid, ARRAY_AGG(m.value) as a
FROM nrs
LEFT JOiN Measures m on m.expid=nrs.expid and m.iteration=nrs.n
GROUP BY nrs.expid
order by nrs.expid
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/GGWe1A1s)

Answer (score 1):

I've once create a [custom aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html) for a similar use case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_set(arr anyarray, index integer, val anyelement) RETURNS anyarray
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $$
  BEGIN
    arr[index] = val;
    RETURN arr;
  END
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE array_by_subscript(integer, anyelement) (
    SFUNC = array_set,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

With this you can fill your new table using

```
INSERT INTO TmpMeasures(expId, values)
SELECT expId, array_by_subscript(iteration, value)
FROM Measures
GROUP BY expId;
```

Comment: [It doesn't scale well](https://dbfiddle.uk/wu86ZN30) but +1 for how clean and elegant it is to use.

Comment: @Zegarek I would say it scales linearly, just as well as the other solutions, it's just really slow… With `PARALLEL SAFE` [I got 10s instead of 13s](https://dbfiddle.uk/xqZu78Qv), but that's still bad, and I'm not quite sure whether this is correct. I suppose there must be a way to speed it up by using a native C function for `array_set` (maybe it already exists and I just didn't find it?).

Comment: Using `array_by_subscript(iteration, value ORDER BY iteration)` [doesn't help either](https://dbfiddle.uk/iM6Z77TM) for speed (though it uses the `measures_pkey` index instead of a hash aggregate, so it takes less memory)

Comment: To be honest, this looks like a good candidate for a proper `internal` implementation rather than a PL/pgSQL add-in. One additional observation is that it produces pruned arrays. It does retain their alignment, so specific subscripts will continue to work and it would only break things if OP relies on prepending/appending. These can also be null-padded afterwards, to re-enable prepending/appending if required: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SyYIsCP5)

Comment: @Zegarek Ah I didn't know that the term "pruned" can be applied to postgres arrays as well. Yes, my actual aggregate also has a `finalfunc = array_fillup` that does `IF array_lower(arr, 1) > 1 THEN arr[1] = NULL; END IF; RETURN arr;` to ensure the array starts at subscript 1 - in my case I needed it so `to_jsonb` would produce the right result, but here it seemed like it wouldn't matter.